# phpmyedit to display positive values

Tags: php, sql

Is there any way to use phpmyedit to display absolute values in the select query.

I don't want negative values to be displayed. I want only positive values to be  displayed. Is there any option in phpmyedit which can have the same functionality as the sql abs(value)

http://www.phpmyedit.org/

Some thing like

```
select abs(values) from table;
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with `phpmyedit` and as such can not provide a proper answer but this part of the documentation seems to cover the issue: http://opensource.platon.sk/projects/doc.php/phpMyEdit/html/configuration.fields.sql.html

Comment: Thanks..:-) Let me check it.